# Symfony - VarDumper component makes the profiler crash

Tags: symfony, dump

When i use dump() function from the VarDumper Component (anything: variable, strings, ints objects), the profiler crashes. The web page shows properly but the profiler won't show up anymore if i use the dump() function.

I have a Javascript error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of null
at load.maxTries ((index):305)
at (index):305
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange ((index):305)
```

And i have no clue of what it is.

I am using Symfony 4.4.18.

Thanks everyone for your help

Comment: Got anything special going on? Docker containers, firewalls etc?  Maybe try F12 in your browser and see what the network monitor is showing.

Comment: Yes i have docker containers but i tried to run the application outside the docker by using the symfony local web server and it's still got the issue.

Comment: Read the end of this [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/26268).  It implies a problem with your security.yaml file.  Maybe it will help.  If you have not already done so, create a fresh 4.4 project, add one simple controller action and then see what happens in your environment.