# symfony profiler not showing when using dump

Tags: php, symfony, debugging, profiler, dump

> I was configuring app when i try to dump some variable,
>
> after that webtoolbar was not on the side.
>
> so i checked sorce of the side and it was here but hiden by css class `sf-display-none`,
>
> also it's generate js error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of null
    at load.maxTries (X42V34HQZP210105GUEST000P01:9)
    at X42V34HQZP210105GUEST000P01:9
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (X42V34HQZP210105GUEST000P01:9)
load.maxTries               @   X42V34HQZP210105GUEST000P01:9
(anonymous)                 @   X42V34HQZP210105GUEST000P01:9
xhr.onreadystatechange      @   X42V34HQZP210105GUEST000P01:9
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)     
window.XMLHttpRequest.send  @   main.js?attr=Z3tot6Y…N_eXJNezrFt8qL:3123
request                     @   X42V34HQZP210105GUEST000P01:9
load                        @   X42V34HQZP210105GUEST000P01:9
loadToolbar                 @   X42V34HQZP210105GUEST000P01:9
(anonymous)                 @   X42V34HQZP210105GUEST000P01:9
(anonymous)                 @   X42V34HQZP210105GUEST000P01:9
```

**Steps to reproduse:**

> 1. Save this as composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.8",
        "openpayu/openpayu": "^2.2",
        "paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk": "^1.0",
        "symfony-bundles/json-request-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/asset": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/cache": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.2.*",
        "twig/twig": "^3.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.11",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.25",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.6",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.8"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.2.*"
        }
    }
}
```

> 2. open terminal in folder that you saved file
> 3. use this commands:

```
composer install && npm install --force
php bin\console make:controller`
```

> > to this moment it's work just fine, but after next step
>
> 4. add this code to the controller index function

```
`dump('test');
```

> profiler not showing after load side and starts geting a js error

Because it work like this on default configuration I really don't have any ideas how to make it work

Comment: Similar to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65520409/symfony-vardumper-component-makes-the-profiler-crash#comment115855368_65520409).  The last comment on the question contains a link to a github issue.  Read to the end of the issue.  It's possible that your security.yaml file is causing the problem.

Comment: But i don't have security.yaml in this project so i don't think this can cause problem.

Comment: For every one with this problem and using kaspersky antivirus. Turn off js injection in option